# Browser sandbox for object interaction testing

Tags: physics, rigid-body-dynamics, prototyping

I’m looking for a sandbox where I can upload/import STL or OBJ files (rigid bodies that I can export from a CAD software) for quick interaction testing with gravity and contact.

The idea is lowest friction possible for import/upload so that the time between file export from CAD software to testing of joints and such will be as quick as possible. So things like creating a sandbox template in Unity and then building the game every time would be out of the question.

Any ideas?

Comment: What difficulty have you encountered building such a sandbox application, that we might be able to help you with?

Comment: @DMGregory I was directed here from gaming SE because requests for recommendations are generally off-topic there.

Comment: They're generally off-topic here too. ;) Let's assume for the moment that your ideal sandbox app doesn't exist. What's our next step then? Well, we have to build it! If we ask about how to build it and it already exists, then surely someone will comment or answer with a relevant link anyway, but at least the "how" question still admits a constructive answer even in the event that no such thing already exists.

Comment: @DMGregory I didn't find a more appropriate SE site for asking for a recommendation. I have spent ~30min in Unity exploring the interface, but other than that I know nothing about the process of game development outside of casually reading articles on game-focused journalistic websites. I am not in a position at the moment to build a sandbox environment. Do you have a suggestion for me about where to solicit help in finding what I seek? I have Googled zealously and found nothing relevant.

Comment: Again: you might have to seriously consider the possibility that no one has already made this tool, if it hasn't shown up in your research to date. You can try the Software Recommendations SE, but I don't have high hopes that they'd find something that didn't appear in your own searching. But, if you want to make this happen, you're in the right place here to get help overcoming challenges in your own development process. Start with some basic tutorials with your framework of choice, and ask here if you run into any confusion or roadblocks.

Comment: @DMGregory I really appreciate your positive response :)